# Display "Loading" Screen during application startup

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm interested how I can display "Loading" message during JavaFX startup. I noticed for example that when I start SceneBuilder I have to wait ~5 seconds before the application is displayed in front of the user. Can I for example display some message during JVM start time?

***UPDATE***

I tested this code:

```
public class test extends Application
{

    private Pane splashLayout;
    private ProgressBar loadProgress;
    private Label progressText;
    private WebView webView;
    private Stage mainStage;
    private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 676;
    private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 227;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image("http://fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/logo.png"));
        loadProgress = new ProgressBar();
        loadProgress.setPrefWidth(SPLASH_WIDTH - 20);
        progressText = new Label("Loading System Modules ...");
        splashLayout = new VBox();
        splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(splash, loadProgress, progressText);
        progressText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        splashLayout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5; -fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-width:5; -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, chocolate, derive(chocolate, 50%));");
        splashLayout.setEffect(new DropShadow());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception
    {
        showSplash(initStage);
        showMainStage();

        webView.getEngine().documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> observableValue, Document document, Document document1)
            {
                if (initStage.isShowing())
                {
                    loadProgress.progressProperty().unbind();
                    loadProgress.setProgress(1);
                    progressText.setText("All Modules Are Loaded!");
                    mainStage.setIconified(false);
                    initStage.toFront();
                    FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2), splashLayout);
                    fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
                    fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);
                    fadeSplash.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                        {
                            initStage.hide();
                        }
                    });
                    fadeSplash.play();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showMainStage()
    {
        mainStage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        mainStage.setTitle("FX Experience");
        mainStage.setIconified(true);

// create a WebView.
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://fxexperience.com/");
        loadProgress.progressProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().divide(100));

// layout the scene.
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 1000, 600);
        webView.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        webView.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();
    }

    private void showSplash(Stage initStage)
    {
        Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
        initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        initStage.setScene(splashScene);
        initStage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - SPLASH_WIDTH / 2);
        initStage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - SPLASH_HEIGHT / 2);
        initStage.show();
    }
}
```

I noticed that the splash image is started with the main stage simultaneity but the main stage is minimized. Can I freeze the appearance of the main stage until the splash screen is completed with the loading. I want to do some internal checks before I display the main stage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `javax.swing.JProgressBar` to achieve this.

Check the details in [JProgressBar](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html&ei=KjeqUdC5JJCkiAekn4CIBw&usg=AFQjCNFPoR7H7b_NLo0CweiKAauelC81Hw&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aGc) (docs)